# Looking for Docusign PHP Code example to send the pdf

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to start Docusign with PHP, but I do not understand how to start with this. I have checked this example :

https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-php/blob/master/src/EG001EmbeddedSigning.php

What I see that this example is doing the process, but how do I call/use this "EG001EmbeddedSigning.php"? I mean how to use this class? What all arguments do we need to pass in to call this? I am looking for a PHP code example, wherein I can include this class & then pass the arguments to this class & send the pdf document.

Also, I have a pdf document & how would I add the "sign here" field to the pdf document with the use of API?

Regards
Nitin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you get the overall example PHP program running. You can use the [QuickStart](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/) to configure the integration key (client id).

The idea is that you see how the example program calls the DocuSign eSignature API, then you copy the relevant parts into your own application.

You can then ask additional questions here on StackOverflow (include the relevant source in your question) when you have issues.